# Formatting a listbox to have 2 values rather than 1

Tags: c#, database, listbox

I am trying to format a textbox so that when it reads from a database, two text values appear on the the same line in the listbox and appear as 1 value

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(reader["FirstName"].ToString());
    listBox1.Items.Add(reader["Surname"].ToString());
    //listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} | {1}", ));
    label2.Visible = true;
    label2.Text = "So far, " + listBox1.Items.Count.ToString() + " people have applied for the " + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " \ncourse." ;
}
```

Where I have put the // is where I am getting stuck, I want the FirstName and Surname to appear next to each. Thanks for any help

Comment: You put `//` where exactly? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for *local variables*:

```
var firstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
var lastname = reader["Surname"].ToString();
//listBox1.Items.Add(firstname);
//listBox1.Items.Add(lastname);
listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} | {1}", firstname, lastname));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
 listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} | {1}",reader["FirstName"].ToString(),reader["Surname"].ToString()));
```